# TypeError: maketrans() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

The following code adapted from a website for removing punctuations from words.

```
import string    
filename = 'some_file.txt'
file = open(filename, 'rt')
text = file.read()
file.close()
# split the text into words
words = text.split()

table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in words]
print(stripped[:100])
```

The error is `"TypeError: maketrans() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"`.
I read the Python documentation that says the options for having 1, 2 or 3 arguments of maketrans(). The docs.python.org says: "If there is a third argument, it must be a string, whose characters will be mapped to None in the result".
I'm using Python 2. Any idea to clear the error?

Comment: If you're using Python 2 it would be [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans), and it takes only two arguments.

Comment: _I read the Python documentation that says the options for having 1, 2 or 3 arguments of maketrans()._ -- Could you provide a link to where you read that?

Comment: I tried your code it is not producing any error in python 3

Comment: agree with @khelwood, python2 doesn;t support 3 argument maketrans function

Comment: palivek, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the python3.1 docs(where in the "If there is a third argument, it...... " statement is mentioned.) with Python2. As per python2 documentation - https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html, it cannot have 3 parameters.

But if you want to achieve the functionality of having a 3rd parameter (to map a set of characters to None), you can do it by adding the string to `translate`,

```
stripped = [w.translate(table, string.punctuation) for w in words]
```

Comment: Now I'm using Python 3.4 and it is producing error `type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'`

Comment: I unistalled Python and Anaconda and re-installed the whole bunch of Anaconda3 with Python 3.6. Now it is properly working. Thanks to all.